# disappear a menu and modify css container

Tags: html, css

I have a site with a navigation bar and a container in the body.
I want to disappear the navigation bar and modify css of my container if the window is less than 1000px.
I have this code :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .headerstandard {
        display: none;
    }
    .container-fluid {
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;   
    }
}

.container-fluid {
    margin-left: 200px; 
}

.vertical_menu {
    margin-top:1%;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    list-style-type: none; 
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

When i resize manually my window, the navigation bar disappear but the container stays with a margin of 200px.
What is the way to do what i want ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Move the `media-query` to the bottom of the css.
The order might be affecting the result.

Answer (score 1):

Add your media below your normal css.
Try this its

```
.container-fluid {
    margin-left: 200px; 
}

.vertical_menu {
    margin-top:1%;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    list-style-type: none; 
    font-size: 13px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .headerstandard {
        display: none;
    }
    .container-fluid {
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;   
    }
}
```